# Why is position().top changing when I scroll the parent?

Tags: jquery, position

jQuery [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) returns

> the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the offset parent.

So, scrolling the parent is *not supposed to change the position*, right?

The result I'm getting in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xqEL/15/) is that after scrolling the parent by 100px, the `position().top` of a child element changes by 100.

> position().top before scroll 1880, after scroll 1780

Why?

Comment: Because `$debug.offsetParent()` is `$('html')`.

Comment: the position is relative to the parent element. The parent element in this case is the scrollable div #box. As you scroll closer to the anchored element, it is closer and closer to the top of the box, resulting in a smaller and smaller top position.

Comment: if you remove overflow, then it will not change. But it makes sense for it to change since the anchored element is getting closer to the top because the div is scrollable due to overflow

Comment: That makes sense, I guess I just remember the behavior wrong.  So how do I get its position irrespective of scrolling?  I guess I'd need a wrapper element for that.

Comment: You can just add the parent element's scroll position to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in your comments, just add the box's scrollTop to the anchored element's position.

http://jsfiddle.net/5xqEL/17/

```
var $box = $('#box'),
    $anchored = $('#anchored'),
    $debug = $('#debug');

$debug.text('position().top before scroll ' + ($anchored.position().top + $box.scrollTop()));

$box.animate({
    scrollTop: 100
}).promise().then(function () {
    $debug.text($debug.text() + ', after scroll ' + ($anchored.position().top + $box.scrollTop()));
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks.  I got it to work with a wrapper element, but this is better.